# Create a 3D shapefile in GDAL

Tags: c++, shapefile, gdal

I'm trying to create a 3D shapefile using GDAL. My code to create a 3D block looks like this:

```
OGRLayer *poLayer = ds->CreateLayer("Floor", NULL, wkbPolygon25D, NULL);
OGRFeature *poFeature;

poFeature = OGRFeature::CreateFeature( poLayer->GetLayerDefn() );

OGRLinearRing ring1, ring2;
OGRPolygon poly;

double x0=y0=z0 = 0;
double x1=y1=z1 = 1;

ring1.addPoint(x0, y0, z0);
ring1.addPoint(x1, y0, z0);
ring1.addPoint(x1, y1, z0);
ring1.addPoint(x0, y1, z0);
ring1.addPoint(x0, y0, z0);
ring1.closeRings();
ring2.addPoint(x0, y0, z1);
ring2.addPoint(x1, y0, z1);
ring2.addPoint(x1, y1, z1);
ring2.addPoint(x0, y1, z1);
ring2.addPoint(x0, y0, z1);
ring2.closeRings();

poly.addRing(&ring1);
poly.addRing(&ring2);
poFeature->SetGeometry(&poly);

poLayer->CreateFeature(poFeature);
```

but, when I open the file later and query a point in the feature:

```
OGRGeometry* pGeometry = pFeature->GetGeometryRef();
OGRSpatialReference* pSpaRef = pGeometry->getSpatialReference();

OGRPoint point(0.5, 0.5,0.5);
point.assignSpatialReference(pSpaRef);    
OGRBoolean bContains = pGeometry->Contains(&point);
```

I get back a result of FALSE.

I've searched through the GDAL documentation and many other places and cannot find any example of how to build a 3D object, so I guess that if you created the top and bottom faces that it would connect them.

So, in summary, the question is...how do I create a 3D block object (like a cube) in GDAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're making two rings - the top and bottom of a "box".  This does not make a closed box (there are no sides), but rather 2 "plates" on top and bottom.

That being said, even if you do make this a closed box, contains will still fail.  This does not do a volumetric contains check, but rather a check to see whether the point is contained within the actual surfaces of the box.  Contains against a point defined as `(0.5, 0.5, 1.0)` should return true (provided OGR is compiled with GEOS), as that point is within the surfaces of the "box".

Comment: I was, I neglected to include that line initially, I've added it as the top line in my source in the question. I think my issue is related to how I'm adding the rings, but I can't find an example to work from.

Comment: @DavidHope Edited my answer - there are other issues at play, as well, but the short answer is this will never work ;)

Comment: not really the answer I wanted to hear, but at least I can stop wasting my time on it :-)

Answer (score 3):

GEOS (used in GDAL) is a 2D geometry engine, but can store coordinates from the third dimension (hence 2.5 dimensions named in `wkbPolygon25D`). Therefore, it effectively evaluates binary predicates between 2D geometries:

```
A: POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0), (0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))
B: POINT(0.5 0.5)
```

Since the two rings in `A` are identical, they "cancel" each other out, and the interior is "erased" (this technique is normally used to put a hole in a polygon). This polygon is considered non-simple, since the rings intersect (remember, it is considered 2D).

GEOS / GDAL cannot be used to perform 3D predicates, like "Contains".